# dynamically adding circles to an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I looked for similar questions before posting this and those solutions are not helping to answer my question.

I've solved this problem by using arrays but using an ArrayList would be better. I've created an event that checks for a left-click to create a circle object and add it to the list. The issue is that when I use this code no circle has been added to the arrayList and it gives no compile errors. How do you add circles to the pane from an ArrayList?

```
    public class test extends Application {
         static int index = 0;
         @Override
         public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         Pane = pane = new Pane();
         ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

         pane.setOnMouseClicked( e -> {

            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {

              circles.add(new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 5));
              circles.get(index).setStroke(Color.BLACK);
              circles.get(index).setFill(Color.WHITE);
              index++;

            }
         });

         pane.getChildren().addAll(circles);

         Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `pane.getChildren().addAll(circles);` within the event handler

Comment: Why do you think the circle hasn't been added to the `ArrayList`? It seems to add the circles just fine.

Comment: @James_D it not showing up in the pane when I click.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll try that now.

Comment: I get an error after the first circle comes up on the pane @MadProgrammer  "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Pane@f8bf52[styleClass=root]" Along with additional error messages.

Comment: Why would it show up in the pane? You have no code to add it to the pane.

Comment: pane.getChildren().addAll(circles) adds the circle nodes to the pane @James_D

Comment: That adds the circles that are in the list at the time you execute it. It's not going to add circles that you add to the list at a later time. (How would it?)

Comment: @James_D do you know how to solve the problem? When pane.getChildren().addAll(circles) is in the event it gives an error. How do you fix it?

Comment: You want me to tell me how to fix an error which you haven't posted in your question?

Comment: @James_D I fixed it. I'll put up the solution soon. I need to add the feature where it moves the the circle with the secondary button and then I'll post. Did you know what the solution was?

Comment: I don't know what the question is. How would I know what the solution is?

Comment: @James_D simply saying you didn't know what the question was because I didn't explicitly type one would have saved a lot of time and would've been just as effective.

Comment: Apologies for my lack of mind-reading ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the circle to the pane, as well as the array list, when you create it:

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked( e -> {

    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {

       Circle circle = new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 5) ;
       circles.add(circle);
       pane.getChildren().add(circle);
       circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
       circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);

       // not sure what index is for. Looks like it would always be
       // equal to circles.size()
       index++;

    }
});
```